# Avaya Supervisor CMS extract data from Report and load it into MySQL

Tags: mysql, vba, content-management-system, report, avaya

*IMPORTANT! This is not a correct way of doing this! It's just a quick hack I need to implement. Connecting directly to Avaya DB would be much better. Windows Task Scheduler is to slow. This will only run on local network.*

**My plan for this quick hack is to:**

1. Login to Avaya CMS Supervisor Version 19.0
2. Run ".acsauto"
3. Extract data into .txt

*which will look like this:*

```
Some Nice Service Desk
2,Martin Scorsese,8869711,5543711,,AVAIL,0,47,
5,Alfred Hitchcock,8869712,5543732,Default,AUX,0,785,
5,Stanley Kubrick,8869714,5543722,Default,AUXOUT,173,85,
2,Francis Ford Coppola,8869715,5543733,,AVAIL,0,1252,
5,John Huston,8869713,5543743,Default,AUXOUT,173,186,
```

4. Finally load it into MySQL 8.0.19
   *Table:*

```
CREATE TABLE `avaya_live_report` (
    `icon_number` TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `agent_name` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `agent_number` INT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `extension` INT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `state_type` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `state` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `zero` TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `time` SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL,
    `empty` TINYTEXT NOT NULL);
```

As it is impossible to schedule **Load Data** as a scheduled reacquiring event on MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\live_report.txt' 
INTO TABLE avaya_live_report
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**I need to connect to MySQL directly from .acsauto script:**

```
'LANGUAGE=ENU
'SERVERNAME=SOME_NICE_IP_ADDRESS
Public Sub Main()

'## begin
'## ID = 1000
'## Description = "Report: Real-Time: Agent: Agent Group Report: Export Data"
'## Parameters.Add "Report: Real-Time: Agent: Agent Group Report: Export Data","_Desc"
'## Parameters.Add "Reports","_Catalog"
'## Parameters.Add "2","_Action"
'## Parameters.Add "1","_Quit"
'## Parameters.Add "Real-Time\Agent\Agent Group Report","_Report"
'## Parameters.Add "1","_ACD"
'## Parameters.Add "1335","_Top"
'## Parameters.Add "2580","_Left"
'## Parameters.Add "6930","_Width"
'## Parameters.Add "4575","_Height"
'## Parameters.Add "default","_TimeZone"
'## Parameters.Add "The report Real-Time\Agent\Agent Group Report was not found on ACD 1.","_ReportNotFound"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_BeginProperties"
'## Parameters.Add "Nice Service Desk","Agent Group"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_EndProperties"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_BeginViews"
'## Parameters.Add "*","_EndViews"
'## Parameters.Add "C:\Scripts\live.txt","_Output"
'## Parameters.Add "9","_FldSep"
'## Parameters.Add "0","_TextDelim"
'## Parameters.Add "False","_NullToZero"
'## Parameters.Add "False","_Labels"
'## Parameters.Add "True","_DurSecs"

   On Error Resume Next

   cvsSrv.Reports.ACD = 1
   Set Info = cvsSrv.Reports.Reports("Real-Time\Agent\Agent Group Report")

   If Info Is Nothing Then
      If cvsSrv.Interactive Then
          MsgBox "The report Real-Time\Agent\Agent Group Report was not found on ACD 1.", vbCritical Or vbOKOnly, "Avaya CMS Supervisor"
      Else
          Set Log = CreateObject("ACSERR.cvsLog") 
          Log.AutoLogWrite "The report Real-Time\Agent\Agent Group Report was not found on ACD 1."
          Set Log = Nothing
      End If
   Else

       b = cvsSrv.Reports.CreateReport(Info,Rep)
       If b Then

          Rep.Window.Top = 1335
          Rep.Window.Left = 2580
          Rep.Window.Width = 6930
          Rep.Window.Height = 4575        


                        Rep.TimeZone = "default"



          Rep.SetProperty "Agent Group","Nice Service Desk"

          ' StackOverflow PLEASE START READING HERE
          ' This loop lets me action something and then wait for 30 seconds in a loop
          For i=1 To 10
          ' This line creates this nice comma separated txt file (Using TXT file is a lot faster then CSV)
            b = Rep.ExportData("C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\live_report.txt", 44, 0, True, False, True)

            Dim dteWait
            '30 sek
            dteWait = DateAdd("s", 30, Now())
            Do Until (Now() > dteWait)
            Loop
            Next




          Rep.Quit



              If Not cvsSrv.Interactive Then cvsSrv.ActiveTasks.Remove Rep.TaskID
          Set Rep = Nothing
       End If

   End If
   Set Info = Nothing
'## cvs_cmd_end

End Sub
```

And I need to integrate this connection to MySQL into above script. Obviously the script below is just VBA Excel script so it makes it quite tricky.

*Connect*

```
conMySQL.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & "SERVER=" & server & ";" & " DATABASE=" & database & ";" & "UID=" & login_user & ";PWD=" & password & "; OPTION=3; PORT=" & port & ";Connect Timeout=20;"

conMySQL.Open
```

*Query*

```
strSQL = "SELECT x FROM some_table"
MySQL.Query (strSQL)

With rsTemporary
      Do Until .EOF
          recordCount = recordCount + 1
          some_variable = ![supcode]
          rsTemporary.MoveNext
      Loop
End With
        MySQL.closeCon
```

I've installed **ODBC driver** already but other then this I just have my Avaya CMS Supervisor Version 19.0 + MySQL 8.0.19 on my dev environment.

**MY QUESTION:**
Did anyone try to integrate this MySQL connection into .acsauto Avaya Script?

Thank you in advance.
KK

Comment: That's your question?  "Did anybody try this?"

Comment: Yea, is this even possible? If someone has a running example that would be great!

Comment: With MySQL 8.0.19 that became General Availability 2020-01-13, is there are REASON you have elected to install software that is less than 2 months old?  Do you have time to report bugs and wait on fixes?  If not, please choose a version that has been GA for at least 6 months to avoid being the person that discovered a bug.  And you could search for MySQL 8.0.19 Changelog and review the already known problems with 8.0.19 at two months of use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mysql odbc 5.1 driver wont work with 8.0.19 server. Character set different, mysql logon password mechanism are different.

Comment: Got it! That a valid point. I will downgrade MySQL version. Do you have any examples of .acauto scripts running with ODBC 5.1? Obviously I'm asking after I already googled it but nothing I found was actually working. Thank you again. I will keep you all updated!

Comment: I am not familiar with ODBC 5.1.  Welcome to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

So, many years ago I had played around with SQL and was able to figure out how to create a table, drop a table, and insert records into a table. Below is inserting records into a Sql table

```
'LANGUAGE=ENU
'SERVERNAME=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Public Sub Main()

   On Error Resume Next

StrConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\QLIS,2026;Database=OADB;UID=xxxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxx"
Set cnt = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnt.Open StrConnect

set recordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQLStr = "Select * from tmpCMSData2 "
recordSet.Open SQLStr, cnt, 1, 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Telecom\COOL_TEXT.txt", 1)

If (objFSO.FileExists("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Telecom\COOL_TEXT.txt")) Then

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

  strCharacter = objFile.Read(1)
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine

  For z = Ubound(strLine) to LBound(strLine) Step -1
    arrProcessLines = Split(strLine,",")
    '##msgbox(arrProcessLines(3))
    cnt.Execute "INSERT INTO tmpCMSData2 (Extension, Workmode, Direction)VALUES(" & arrProcessLines(0) & "," & arrProcessLines(1) & "," & arrProcessLines(2) & ")"
  Next

Loop

else
  strFileExists = Msgbox("no")
End If

End Sub
```

Creating a table is:

```
cnt.Execute "CREATE TABLE tmpCMSData2 (Extension int,Workmode int,Direction int, Duration int, Split int, OnHold int, ACD int, AuxReason int, LogID int, CID varchar(25))"
```

An example of the data I was importing in the COOL_TEXT.txt file is:

```
Extn,State,Direction,Time,Split/Skill,ONHOLD,ACD,AUX Reason,Login ID
21281,AUX,0,327,10,0,1,General,42554
17334,AUX,0,1049,10,0,1,General,47322
68909,AUX,IN,71,10,0,1,General,45466
16425,AUX,0,11856,10,0,1,General,48103
16322,AUX,0,2773,10,0,1,General,45955
21394,AVAIL,0,278,10,0,1,,47633
17501,AUX,0,10463,10,0,1,General,48513
16360,AUX,0,3811,10,0,1,General,45996
21305,AUX,0,10229,10,0,1,General,44873
```

Hope this helps!

Dave M.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same as Dave M. I write the data to a file then loop the file to insert data into the database. For historical data, I use informix to pull the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).